# The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions, eventhough sequence length is the same

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network, spectrogram

I'm building an RNN model that reads spectrograms files.  When I'm extracting features and labels and and assigning it to X & y, then try to convert it to numpy array, I would get this error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (1440, 128) + inhomogeneous part.
I made sure that the length of sequence of features in X is the same, which is 128.  Therefore, I'm confused why I'm getting this error, when the length is the same.  More, I tried to add padding, but still did not work and I would get a different kind of error.  I would highly appreciate any kind of feedback.  Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.